# Passing ArrayList of objects through intent - Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I am trying to pass an ArrayList of objects through an intent but cannot get it to work.  Here is what I have:

```
public class QuestionView extends Activity {

    //variables and other methods...

    public void endQuiz() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionView.this, Results.class);
        intent.putExtra("correctAnswers", correctAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("wrongAnswers", wrongAnswers);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("queries", queries);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Intents are being received here:

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    int cAnswers;
    int wAnswers;
    ArrayList<Question> qs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resultsmain);

        cAnswers = getIntent().getIntExtra("correctAnswers", -1);
        wAnswers = getIntent().getIntExtra("wrongAnswers", -1);

        qs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");

                    //more code...
    }
}
```

The two ints, correctAnswer and wrongAnswers, are being received and I can use them.  The ArrrayList is not coming through.  No errors on in the endQuiz() method but the 'qs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");' is throwing an error and saying "Bound Mismatch."

Any help on this is appreciated!

Question class:

```
public class Question {
    String a1;
    String a2;
    String a3;
    String a4;
    int correctAnswer;
    String query;
    int selectedAnswer;
    boolean correctness;

    public Question() {
    }

    public Question(String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4, int correctAnswer, String query, int selectedAnswer, boolean correctness) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
        this.a4 = a4;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        this.query = query;
        this.selectedAnswer = selectedAnswer;
        this.correctness = correctness;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `Question` class implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)?

Comment: no ... thats why he is casting it ... `(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) queries);` :) which certainly will not help

Comment: Can we see what the type of your queries ArrayList actually looks like? I mean the class...

Comment: @Selvin, but he's not getting class cast exception which is curious...

Comment: java generics ... similar code will not compile in C# but in java ... `ArrayList<Object> a = null; ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> b = (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) a;` works ... with only warrning `Unchecked cast from ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>` .... in java at runtime you don't know generic type

Comment: I edited in my opening post the Question class which shows what the ArrayList is composed of.  The ArrayList is composed of Question objects:  ArrayList<Question>

Comment: your Question class should implement Parcelable then,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must change your `Question` class to actually implement Parcelable. The Parcelable interface can be confusing at first... but hang in there.

There are two Parcelable methods that you should focus on:

- `writeToParcel()` which converts your class into a Parcel object.
- `Question(Parcel in)` which converts a Parcel object back into usable instance of your class.

You can safely cut & paste the other Parcelable information that I marked.

For the sake of simplicity I will only use part of your Question class:

```
public class Question implements Parcelable {
    String a1;
    String a2;
    ...

    public Question(String a1, String a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
    }

    // Your existing methods go here. (There is no need for me to re-write them.) 

    // The following methods that are required for using Parcelable
    private Question(Parcel in) {
        // This order must match the order in writeToParcel()
        a1 = in.readString();
        a2 = in.readString();
        // Continue doing this for the rest of your member data
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        // Again this order must match the Question(Parcel) constructor
        out.writeString(a1);
        out.writeString(a2);
        // Again continue doing this for the rest of your member data
    }

    // Just cut and paste this for now
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // Just cut and paste this for now
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Question> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Question>() {
        public Question createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Question(in);
        }

        public Question[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Question[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Now change how you put `queries` into your Intent extras.

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("queries", queries);
```

The way you read the Parcelable array is perfect as it is.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer Sam!  I did not give you all my code so I might have thrown you off course.  I edited my opening post with all my classes.  Now with that, should I implement Parcelable and add all those other methods in QuestionView or Question?

Comment: You only want to pass an ArrayList of Questions, so only the Question class should implement Parcelable

Comment: Oh man it works!  This is the furthest I have been in the 2 months I have been working on this.  Huge milestone today!  Thank you again Sam.  :)

Comment: @Sam how to parcel a bitmap?

Answer (score 7):

In order to be able to deliver an ArrayList as part of an Intent, your type must implement Parcelable. Judging by the fact you had to cast your List to `(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>)`, you didn't do this. If you had, you could simply have:

```
class Foo implements Parcelable {
//implementation here
}
ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
new Intent().putParcelableArrayListExtra("foos", foos); //no need to cast
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to implement Parcelable but using Serializable for this involves a performance penalty, so you actually should use Parcelable.