# How can I pass this ArrayList to a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist

I am trying to pass this ArrayList to another activity.
So far my efforts have been a failure. 
I know that I am not understanding how to pass it correctly.

Here is the arrayList code that I have:

```
public static ArrayList<Movie> getMovieItems() {
        if(mItems == null) {
            mItems = new ArrayList<>();

            Movie movie1 = new Movie();
            movie1.setId(1);
            movie1.setTitle("Title1");
            movie1.setStudio("studio1");
            movie1.setDescription("description1");
            movie1.setCardImageUrl("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ZKjKucsPdzI/TudWC99CE_I/AAAAAAAAAD8/qvWdDtw5IW0/s1600/%2528393%2529.jpg");
            //movie1.setVideoUrl("http://corochann.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/MVI_0949.mp4");
            /* Google sample app's movie */
            //movie1.setVideoUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/VopbGPJVkzM");
            //movie1.setVideoUrl("http://live.gph.gov.sa/makkahlive/");
            //movie1.setVideoUrl("http//livestreaming2.itworkscdn.net/squranlive/squran_7200p");

            /// --- try this

            //String url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/VopbGPJVkzM";

            //movie1.setVideoUrl("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/android-tv/Sample%20videos/Demo%20Slam/Google%20Demo%20Slam_%2020ft%20Search.mp4");
            movie1.setVideoUrl("http//livestreaming2.itworkscdn.net/squranlive/squran_360p");
            mItems.add(movie1);


            Movie movie2 = new Movie();
            movie2.setId(2);
            movie2.setTitle("Title2");
            movie2.setStudio("studio2");
            movie2.setDescription("description2");
            movie2.setCardImageUrl("http://www.questionsonislam.com/sites/default/files/mescid-i-nebevi.jpg");
            //movie2.setVideoUrl("http://corochann.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/MVI_0962.mp4");
            /* Google sample app's movie */
            movie2.setVideoUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/4OoKpZWJASY");
            mItems.add(movie2);

            Movie movie3 = new Movie();
            movie3.setId(3);
            movie3.setTitle("Title3");
            movie3.setStudio("studio3");
            movie3.setDescription("description3");
            movie3.setCardImageUrl("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ju9FXyjDFqI/TgY7uVabgxI/AAAAAAAAADw/-qSdxfyHosM/s1600/masjid+qiblatain+%25283%2529.gif");
            //movie3.setVideoUrl("http://corochann.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/MVI_1112.mp4");
            movie3.setVideoUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/4OoKpZWJASY");
            mItems.add(movie3);

        }
        return mItems;
    }
```

mItems is the ArrayList that I want to pass to another activity.
I tried this "template"

```
ArrayList<Movie> chanList= new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I realized that I don't have it correct.

Can someone help me out with some insight tutelage and help me understand how to do this correctly?

Thanks!

ironmantis7x

Comment: by another class, you mean another activity?

Comment: yes I meen another activity. Sorry I confused anyone.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing ArrayList of objects through intent - Java (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709362/passing-arraylist-of-objects-through-intent-java-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this solution what I did was:
I wrote a class file to pull the youTubeID of the stream. 
I then made the YouTubeID of the stream a variable that I put into the ArrayList. Now I can chose the yoyTubeID of the stream as a variable and all works now!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make your `Movie` class implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) in order to pass it through Activities using intents.

**EDIT:** An example of your class implementing `Parcelable`:

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {

    // I'm assuming that's what you have inside your class.
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String studio;
    private String description;
    private String imageURL;
    private String videoURL;

    public Movie() { }

    // Getters and Setters here
    //...

    // Read the Parcel in the same order you wrote it.
    public Movie(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.studio = in.readString();
        this.description = in.readString();
        this.imageURL = in.readString();
        this.videoURL = in.readString();
    }

    // Some dumb method, just leave it as it is.
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // Write your data to Parcel, remember, you'll have to read in the same order you wrote here.
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeString(title);
        out.writeString(studio);
        out.writeString(description);
        out.writeString(imageURL);
        out.writeString(videoURL);
    }

    public static final Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Creator() {
        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new Movie(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int i) {
            return new Movie[i];
        }
    };
}
```

After you do that, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable), this [this tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/) and [this one](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html), for further information.

TL;DR: You'll have to use [`Intent#putParcelableArrayListExtra`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)) on the sender Activity, and [`Intent#getParcelableArrayListExtra`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String)) on the second Activity.

Comment: Thanks @Mauker. Can you please give me a dummy example?

Comment: Great answer! Just a small typo: The Creator class uses a generic, it should be `public static final Creator<Movie> CREATOR...` Android Studio would have highlighted that for the OP though, but worth fixing. Another typo is writing the id `out.writeString(id);`. Should be `out.writeInt(id);`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Adam! Fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

First step is to make your model **Parcelable**, [check here for instructions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable)

Next is to put your array list in the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("some string identifier", yourArrayList);
startActivity(intent)
```

Then in your next activity, get the array list using this:

```
 ArrayList<Movie> chanList = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("some string identifier");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your movie class Parcelable. If your movie class is a POJO you can easily do it using http://www.parcelabler.com/

Then you can do directly put it in intent and pass it through :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key_string", movieArrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Sharedprefrence to store list

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefrence", 0); 

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

  String movie_data = gson.toJson(mItems);

  editor.putString("MovieDatas", task_data);

  editor.commit()
```

and for access

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefrence", 0);

  String json=sharedPreferences.getString("MovieDatas","");

  Type type=new TypeToken<ArrayList<Movie>>(){}.getType();

  mItems = new ArrayList<Movie>();

  mItems=New Gson().fromjson(json,type);
```